# using findOne in mongodb to find by id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, vuejs2, mean-stack

I'm making a tapTracker app with MEVN stack and there is a page with all of songs 
and i want that when i click on a single song make app to open this single song only ...

***IN THE FRONT END ==>***

so i make route from **songs.vue** '{that songs page}' to **viewSong.vue**

```
<v-btn dark class="cyan darken-3" v-on:click="navigateTo({name: 'song', 
 params: {songId: song._id}})"> View </v-btn>
```

after that in **viewsong.vue** i make a show function with id param

```
<template>
  <h1></h1>
</template>

<script>
import songsServices from '@/services/songsServices'
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      song: null
    }
  },
  async mounted () {
    const songId = this.$store.state.route.params.songId
    this.song = await songsServices.show(songId)
  }
}
</script>
```

then i make an api with it to send that to back-end server in

**songServices.js**

```
show (songId) {
  return Api().get(`songs/${songId}`)
}
```

***IN THE BACK END 'SERVER' ==>***

i make get http req in **router.js**

```
app.get('/songs/:songId', songsController.show)
```

**songsController.js**

```
async show(req,res) {
    try {
      const Song = await Songs.findOne({_id: req.params.songId})
        res.send(song)

    } catch (error) {
      res.status(400).send('error: error when tring to fetch songs!!!')
      console.log(error)
    }
  }
```

in postman when i make a get req with this param it give me error
where is the problem ??

**hint** this is the project url on github

**https://github.com/mohamedAdel01/tapTracker**

Comment: What's the error you get?

Comment: ReferenceError: song is not defined
    at show (D:\programing\MEVN-APP\server\controlles\songsController.js:16:20)
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
::1 - - [06/Nov/2017:16:05:55 +0000] "GET /songs/59eca49178b95f057c225c14 HTTP/1.1" 400 2 "-" "PostmanRuntime/6.4.1"

Comment: Ah right, because you've got a typo where you named it `Song`. :-)

Comment: and in post man the error is   'error: error when tring to fetch songs!!!'

Comment: so what's can i do

Comment: :-) Fix the typo? `const song = await ...`

Comment: thank you very much ,iam very fool :), how could i forget that

Comment: No worries. Next time be sure to read and understand the error message and do more debugging before posting.

Comment: okay got it, thank you again